# Get data from sql server into textbox error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

```
protected void DropDownServerName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string serverName = DropDownServerName.SelectedValue;

        string sqlquery = ("SELECT Architecture FROM tblServer WHERE (ServerName = " + serverName + ")");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

        txtUpdateArchitecture.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

The DropDownServerName aready connected to SQL Server using SqlDataSource to show list of values on ServerName column.

After I get select value called "Brad" and I want value from Architecture column from Brad to show up on textbox. However I got error say, Invalid column name "Brad". The column is suppose to be ServerName and Brad is just a value in ServerName column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. It should work with the single quotes.

```
string sqlquery = ("SELECT Architecture FROM tblServer WHERE ServerName = '" + serverName + "'");
```

Comment: never concatenate like that , use paramaters

Answer (score 3):

You need quote around your servername

```
string sqlquery = ("SELECT Architecture FROM tblServer WHERE (ServerName = '" + serverName + "')");
```

Or better still, use Parameterized query [it is safer, against SQL Injection and funny characters in string that can pollute your query]

```
string sqlquery = "SELECT Architecture FROM tblServer WHERE ServerName = @ServerName";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerName", serverName);
```

Comment: Better yet, use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: nice , other  are  telling this guy to concatenate rather then telling him to use parameters

Comment: Maybe SO should have some algorithm to detect this and would redirect to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection or something similar :)

Answer (score 0):

add ' ' around servername in the WHERE clause:

```
... WHERE ServerName = '" + serverName + "' ...
```

Comment: never concatenate like that , use paramaters

Answer (score 0):

You probably are missing single quotes around the variable. Try this

```
    protected void DropDownServerName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string serverName = DropDownServerName.SelectedValue;

        string sqlquery = ("SELECT Architecture FROM tblServer WHERE (ServerName = '" + serverName + "')");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

        txtUpdateArchitecture.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You have introduced more syntax error into that query with the **wrong placement** of the quotes. But I didn't downvote

Comment: @codingbiz thanks I have corrected it though my answer is not correct. Others have posted correct answer about using parameterized query instead of using  single quotes in the same query.

Comment: Your answer is correct but is discouraged for security reason.